# selecting day from dropdown in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, drop-down-menu, webdriver

[image]

[image]

Selecting day month and year from **drop down** it showing error in Firefox and chrome both by **selenium** web driver in java.

Please tell me how to do this type of drop down

Comment: don't post code as images.

Comment: Please POST a question  with proper details like element HTML snippet, code effort What did you tried so far and the complete stack trace So it may easier to understand your problem and someone help you out

Comment: I guess, you are using deselectByIndex() method instead of selectByIndex(). please try with selectByIndex(1) or selectByVisibleText("April").

Comment: material design select input drop down  is this type of dropdown is possible in selenium

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public void selectDropdownOption(WebDriver driver, By by, String value)
{
    Select selectList = new Select(driver.findElement(by));
    selectList.selectByValue(value);
}

Usage:

selectDropdownOption(driver, By.xpath("//select[@id='dob_month']"), "December");
```

I hope this helps you!